# How to find the Maximum value for specific key in List<TreeMap<Integer,Integer>>?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, treemap

Would you please help me to find the maximum value for each key from list of map:
the list of map is like below:

```
[{47=96, 82=189, 100=231, 125=279, 158=322, 240=375},
 {47=125, 82=239, 100=285, 125=334, 158=378, 240=429},
 {47=119, 82=170, 100=182, 125=188, 158=188, 240=170}]
```

How to find max of value for each key? For example, the max value for the key 47 is 125, I need to find the max value of each key.

```java
List<TreeMap<Integer, Integer>> listOfFreq = new ArrayList<>();

for (int thisFreq : frequencyList) {
    int max = listOfFreq.stream()
            .mapToInt(map -> map.getOrDefault(thisFreq, Integer.MIN_VALUE))
            .max().orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flatten the entrySet of map using `flatMap` and collect as new map using `Collectors.toMap` with max value as the value of the key.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> res = 
    listOfFreq.stream()
              .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(), Integer::max));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier,downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) method for this purpose:

```java
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> listOfFreq = List.of(
        // k1, v1, k2, v2, k3, v3, k4, v4, k5, v5, k6, v6
        Map.of(47, 96, 82, 189, 100, 231, 125, 279, 158, 322, 240, 375),
        Map.of(47, 125, 82, 239, 100, 285, 125, 334, 158, 378, 240, 429),
        Map.of(47, 119, 82, 170, 100, 182, 125, 188, 158, 188, 240, 170));

Map<Integer, Integer> mapOfMaxFreq = listOfFreq
        // Stream<Map<Integer,Integer>>
        .stream()
        // Stream<Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>>
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        // stream over all entries of all maps
        // Stream<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        // looking for a max value for each key in
        // all map entries and collect them to map
        // Map<Integer,Optional<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))))
        // Collection<Optional<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>>
        .values()
        // Stream<Optional<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>>
        .stream()
        // get value if present or else (0, 0)
        // Stream<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>
        .map(entry -> entry.orElse(Map.entry(0, 0)))
        // collect to map
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(mapOfMaxFreq);
// {240=429, 82=239, 100=285, 125=334, 158=378, 47=125}
```